# How to keep track of the number of clients that are connecting to server

Tags: sockets, http, load-balancing

I'm building a software agent that run on a server, this software agent act as a server manager i.e. starting/stoping Docker container, monitoring etc.
This server will host/serve many services, these services are programs running in Docker container, 1 program/service per container.
There may be so many servers and these servers aren't necessary be a high performance server, they ranges from a small VM to high performance computer. Right now, I assume that every service uses HTTP to serve request.

The function that I want to implement in this software agent is tracking the number of clients that are currently connecting (requesting) to server for every service (e.x. server A is processing 500 requests) or specific program is ok (e.x. program A is processing 100 requests, program B is processing 200 request).
I want to know this number because I want to do workload balancing across servers that host the same service.
The following is ideas that I have.

1. Implementing load balancer/reverse proxy inside this agent (I would use this load balancer https://github.com/nwoodthorpe/Load-Balancer-Golang).  This may be the last choice because I think it will use pretty much resources for load balancing.
2. Letting service programs that are running on server tell agent whenever they start and finish processing request.  I simply implement UDP socket server in agent to listen for a datagram that tell unique ID of request (actually, can be anything that help me distinguish specific request that being processed) and status whether is being processed or finish processing.

So, I would like to ask for a suggestion for above approaches, which one is better or how should I implement it?  Is there any better approach to do this?

Comment: There's too much words in the question so IMO the essense of the question is obscured IMO. Do I understand correctly that 1) you want to write a server program in Go; 2) You want to know how much clients are having their HTTP requests being processed by that program at any given time? I mean that program alone. Not the whole VM, not a whole cluster you have talked about. Am I correct?

Comment: @kostix 1.Yes, a server program which I called it "agent" that act as a server manager i.e. start/stop new container(programs will be run inside container), monitoring etc. programs that runs inside container could be anything but expose their service via HTTP. And isn't necessary need to be written in GO, though I prefer GO.  2.I want to know how many clients are having their HTTP request being processed by programs e.x. program A is currently processing 100 requests, program B is currently processing 50 requests.  I'm also going to edit my question.

Comment: Usually the load balancer keeps track of that because it's already proxying the requests; it knows at any given moment how many active requests are being forwarded to each instance in the pool. There should be no need for the services themselves to track this for the load balancer.

Comment: @Adrian I'm trying to find another solution that doesn't proxy request for the reason that I said earlier.  In my work, it's so difficult to place separate load balancer server in the network.

Comment: Your question states "I want to do workload balancing across servers that host the same service". If you want to balance load without a load balancer, you're going to have to provide some more details on what exactly it is you're trying to do.